# get parameter with url in freeswitch <param />

Tags: spring-mvc, freeswitch

I'm using Freeswitch and I need to hit a url by  in `xml_cdr.conf.xml` like,

```
<configuration name="xml_cdr.conf" description="XML CDR CURL logger">
  <settings>
    <param name="url" value="http://localhost:8080/ftpTransferPerCall?uuid=${uuid}"/>
  </settings>
....
</configuration>
```

but it gives error like,

> ```
> [ERR] mod_xml_cdr.c:395 Got error [400] posting to web server [http://localhost:8080/ftpTransferPerCall?uuid=${uuid}]
> [ERR] mod_xml_cdr.c:402 Retry will be with url [http://localhost:8080/ftpTransferPerCall?uuid=${uuid}]
> [ERR] mod_xml_cdr.c:418 Unable to post to web server, writing to file
> ```

and it write a file in `/usr/local/freeswitch/log/xml_cdr` name with `<uuid_values>.cdr.xml`

i want to hit this url and get it in my controller ,

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/ftpTransferPerCall", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void ftpTransferSingle(@RequestParam(value="uuid", required = false) String uuid)  { 
  System.err.println("In Ftptransfer:- "+uuid);
}
```

Is there any way to hit this url as post and get it in Controller and not get Downloaded files in `/usr/local/freeswitch/log/xml_cdr/<uuid_values>.cdr.xml`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is address `http://localhost:8080/ftpTransferPerCall` certainly available from server where the freeswitch is running ?

Try 
`curl -x POST http://localhost:8080/ftpTransferPerCall`

I mean this isn't problem with freeswitch.